# Programmatically detect all keyboards which are set in my iPhone settings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2, custom-keyboard

How do I know, how much keyboards enabled into my iPhone keyboard settings.

Even if user downloaded other custom keyboard from app store, still I want in list programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *keyboards = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] objectForKey:@"AppleKeyboards"]; // Array of all active keyboards

NSLog(@"List of all keyboards : %@",keyboards);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work on ios8 sim... (didn't check on a ios8 device), but does work on >=9 sim/device.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask current first responder (UITextField, UISearchBar, etc.).

// assume you have instance variable pointing to search bar currently entering

```
UITextInputMode *inputMode = [self.searchBar textInputMode];
NSString *lang = inputMode.primaryLanguage;
```